# removeEventListener seems to not remove the listener

Tags: apache-flex, event-handling

I wrote this actionscript code:

```
trace("before remove: " +
    donneesTechniques.hasEventListener(DonneesTechniques.INITIALISATION) );
donneesTechniques.removeEventListener(DonneesTechniques.INITIALISATION, init);
trace("after remove: " +
    donneesTechniques.hasEventListener(DonneesTechniques.INITIALISATION) );
```

the output of this code is:

```
before remove: true
after remove: true
```

How is that possible? The `donneesTechniques` component has a lister for the `INITIALISATION` event but it seems not to remove it...

I checked the memory addresses of this component through the code and it is always the same address. So there is no remove on another object. removeEventListener does not have any effect if the listener is not found but in my case there is one (according to `hasEventListener()`)

Comment: Actual answer: Stop using as3's magical string event system, and switch to something far faster, and efficent as3 signals.  http://johnlindquist.com/2010/01/21/as3-signals-tutorial/   No really, they offer far more benifits and it's easy to keep track and remove them.

Comment: Since I'm an intern working on an already existing (but so bugged) project, I'll ask my team if this could be interesant. Thank you very much BTW, I'll look at this for my personal projects!

Comment: I talked to the rest of the team and they were convinced by this Signal Slot approach! Many thanks for this link JTtheGeek!

Comment: Glad you like that, you should also check out RobotLegs - http://www.robotlegs.org/ as well :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `hasEventListener()` there is **at least** one listener. So it is very possible if some other component subscribed this event too and is still subscribed after you removed a listener in current object.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Do you know how I can check the # of listeners?

Comment: It is very pity but there is no way to determinate this :(

Comment: Oh! ok... I'll continue my investigations then...

The strange thing is that sometimes the listener is removed... That could mean it is added more than once after the first removal or am I wrong?

Comment: I believe listener removes every time you call `removeEventListener()` (if current object subscribed to it with event handler passed). But if no any other objects subscribed `hasEventListener()` can be `false`. Another thing which can cause your problem is the case when current object subscribes twice or more times.

Comment: Here is the addEventListener part too: http://pastebin.com/73FFnkyS

I'm using PureMVC Framework and every time the user displays the `DonneesTechniques` component, the `MediateurDonneesTechniques` is called and adds the eventListener and when the user changes the module he's displaying, the handleNotification is called and should remove the eventListener, but it doesn't always do it...

Comment: I recommend you to find all the places in code where called `addEventListener()` for `DonneesTechniques` then pace breakpoint there and count how many times `addEventListener()` calls. Or even better. You can override `addEventListener()` of `DonneesTechniques` and place counter there to count haw many times it called per instance. Don't forget about calling `super.addEventListener`! :)

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you a lot for the time you spend on my problem :)

Comment: @Constantiner let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3034/discussion-between-nicolas-w-and-constantiner)